# Dockerized spring boot unable to access jarfile

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I have a spring boot 3 application that I am trying to deploy on a docker container on an M1 macbook. I am getting error when trying to run the container:

```bash
docker run -p 8080:8080 myapp_backend:0.0.1
Error: Unable to access jarfile /app.jar
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17 AS build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY ./src ./src
RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

# Stage 2
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim AS production-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/target/*.jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

Docker build logs:

```
> docker build -t myapp_backend:0.0.1 .      
[+] Building 3.2s (15/15) FINISHED                                                                                                                   docker:rancher-desktop
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 735B                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim                                                                                                 3.2s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17                                                                                              3.2s
 => [build-stage 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17@sha256:7106ce47b5c226ee21bac386cb706ff9f3db7ac2f15e251e3aa491fcbfc30028                            0.0s
 => [production-stage 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/openjdk:17-jdk-slim@sha256:aaa3b3cb27e3e520b8f116863d0580c438ed55ecfa0bc126b41f68c3f62f9774                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.64kB                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [production-stage 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 3/6] COPY pom.xml .                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 4/6] RUN mvn dependency:go-offline                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 5/6] COPY ./src ./src                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [build-stage 6/6] RUN mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [production-stage 3/3] COPY --from=build-stage /app/target/*.jar app.jar                                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f5ca156d9ebda2118100dc1d75ec6240f3e9c283686ea51599cad313bf5744c8                                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/myapp_backend:0.0.1                                                                                                           0.0s
```

Comment: If you have a spring boot application strongly consider using its way to build docker images. For more complex applications this will give better images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/target/*.jar app.jar
```

your app.jar goes to `/app/app.jar`, not `/app.jar`. The current directory in docker image build is always the latest `WORKDIR`.

Yet in your entrypoint you have this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

where you try to run the `app.jar` from the root (`/`) directory.

You have two good options. Either

1. Copy the `app.jar` to the correct place under root: `COPY --from=build-stage /app/target/*.jar /app.jar`

or

2. Run the `app.jar` from the correct place under `/app/app.jar`:
   `ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]`